# Page not updating when clicking submit

Tags: javascript, html

I have HTML and JavaScript code, which must, after clicking submit, change the page. The problem is, when I click the submit button, the page remains the same.

Thanks for the help.

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>MyApp</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="cart" action="/page" method="POST">
      <div id="navigation">Select ID:
        <select id="state" type="text">
          <option value>-select-</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div>           
      <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function() {
  "use strict";
  var state = document.getElementById('state');
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('cart').addEventListener('submit', estimateTotal);
    var btnEstimate = document.getElementById('submit');
    btnEstimate.disabled = true;
    state.addEventListener('change', function() {

      if (state.value === '') {
        btnEstimate.disabled = true;
      } else {
        btnEstimate.disabled = false;
      }
    });
  });

  function estimateTotal(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (state.value === '') {
      alert('Please choose your shipping state.');
      state.focus();
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: That is because you have event.preventDefault() when you press the button, that disable the standard submit event of form.

Comment: You `preventDefault()` when the form is submitted, so your form is not being sent...